# Python - try-except warning

Tags: python, warnings, try-except

I've recently had a problem when coding in Python in the PyCharm editor. Whenever I made a try-except statement, I would for some reason get a warning (yellow line beneath the word: except)

Here is an example:

```
s = "Text"

try:
    print(s[2])
except:
    print("There is no character at that index")
```

When I write this exact code in PyCharm, I get a warning. When I hover my mouse over the warning it says:

```
Too broad exception clause 
PEP 8: E722 do not use bare 'except'
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: A bare `except` will catch all types of exceptions, and according to PEP8, doing this is discouraged. It's good practice to be specific. In your case, you would want to only catch `IndexError` exceptions by doing: `except IndexError:`.

Comment: How can I figure out the exact type of exception thrown in a code base I didn't write and the original coders are GONE? These kinds of fake errors are just wasting developer's time, making me mad, and fixing them doesn't bring much value to the code.

Answer (score 0):

When catching exceptions, mention specific exceptions whenever possible instead of using a bare except: clause.

For example:

```
try:
    import platform_specific_module
except ImportError:
    platform_specific_module = None
```

A bare except: clause will catch SystemExit and KeyboardInterrupt exceptions, making it harder to interrupt a program with Control-C, and can disguise other problems. If you want to catch all exceptions that signal program errors, use except Exception: (bare except is equivalent to except BaseException: ).

A good rule of thumb is to limit use of bare 'except' clauses to two cases:

If the exception handler will be printing out or logging the traceback; at least the user will be aware that an error has occurred.

If the code needs to do some cleanup work, but then lets the exception propagate upwards with raise . try...finally can be a better way to handle this case.